# Full calendar - Can not refresh events in react

Tags: fullcalendar

I use Full Calendar in my React project. I can not refresh the calendar although I make an update on the state.

Here is my sample code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/fullcalendar-react-jp7n1

In this sample, I change the title of events when user clicks on the Change title button, but nothing changes. I there anything that I miss?

Thanks for your help.

```js
import React from "react";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"; 
import "./styles.css";
import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();

  state = {
    calendarWeekends: true,
    calendarEvents: [
      // initial event data
      { title: "Event 1", start: new Date() },
      { title: "Event 2", start: new Date() },
      { title: "Event 3", start: new Date() }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-app">
        <div className="demo-app-top">
          <button onClick={this.changeTitle}>Change title</button>
        </div>
        <div className="demo-app-calendar">
          <FullCalendar
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            header={{
              left: "prev,next today",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
            }}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
            weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
            events={this.state.calendarEvents}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  changeTitle = () => {   
    let events = [...this.state.calendarEvents];
    events[0].title = new Date().toTimeString();
    events[1].title = new Date().toTimeString();

    this.setState({ calendarEvents: events });
  };
}
```

Comment: Please include your sample code in your question rather than as a link. Include the minimal code needed to reproduce your error. Also, include the results you are getting. What happens when you try to refresh your calendar?

Comment: I am sorry for this inconvenience. I updated the description. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full calendar uses deep equality check to test for changes and since the object of the event inside the array is not changed (it's the  same object by reference) it doesn't detect the change. You need to create a new event object to update it.

```
let events = [ ...this.state.calendarEvents];

    events[0] = {
      title: new Date().toTimeString(),
      start: events[0] .start
    }
    events[1] = {
      title: new Date().toTimeString(),
      start: events[1].start
    }

    this.setState({ calendarEvents: events});
```